# Model receber context no MVP do Android

Tags: android

Tenho um banco sqlite, para utilizar preciso do context, porém, mandar o context para o presenter e depois pro model seria uma violação do MVP, pois ele faz parte da view, faz parte do Android.
Como eu usaria o context sem violar o MVP?

No caso, passar pro presenter seria assim:

```
interface Model {
    String getUser();
    String getPassword();
}

interface View {
    void showToast(String message);
    void emptyUsuarioEditText();
    void emptyPasswordEditText();
    Context getContext();
}

interface Presenter {
    void login(String user, String password);
    Context getContext();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, você não precisa de um `Context` propriamente dito. O que você precisa é de uma referência a uma classe que extenda `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Digamos, uma classe `Database`:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
...
}
```

Essa classe, por sua vez, precisa de um `Context`.

Existem várias formas diferentes de você passar uma referência desse `Database` para o seu model. Você pode criar um método `static` na sua classe `Application` que retorna pra você uma instância da classe `Database`.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static Database getDatabase() {
        return new Database(getContext());
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
       return sInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Desse modo basta fazer no seu Model (ou no Presenter e envie dele para o Model):

```
MyApplication.getDatabase();
```

Apesar de funcionar eu não gosto muito dessa abordagem. Não acho certo fazer isso na classe Application.

Assim, você poderia ter uma classe, digamos: `Injection`. Onde você realiza "DI na mão".

```
public final class Injection {

    private Injection() {
        throw new IllegalStateException(Injection.class.getSimpleName() + " cannot be instantiated!");
    }

    public static Database provideDatabase() {
        return new Database(MyApplication.getContext());
    }
}
```

Uma outra alternativa ainda, é caso você utilize Dagger, por exemplo, deixar ele fazer a injeção de dependência automática da classe `Database` no seu Model.

Comment: Eu li sobre a solução da application, e dizem ser ruim pois atrapalha o teste, e é meio gambiarra (pelo que falam)...
Eu também não posso utilizar o dagger

Comment: Se eu eu enviar a classe Database para o presenter, estarei violando o MVP também? Não somente o sqlite, mas também existem outras coisas que usam context, como o sharedpreference...

Comment: @felipe.rce Buscar o `Context` da `Application` utilizando a classe `Injection` não é gambiarra. Muitas vezes precisamos fazer isso pois precisamos de algo que exista por toda a aplicação. É por isso que é lá que inicamos algumas libs, como o Dagger. E isso não faz o Dagger ser gambiarra. Você só deve saber usar nos momentos certos.

Comment: é que, muitas respostas no stackoverflow, apontam que manter o context estático na application não é uma boa solução (veja os comentários): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100105/need-context-in-model-in-mvp

Praticamente todas perguntas por lá tinham respostas assim, e comentários apontando que é errado

Comment: @felipe.rce Sobre a `SharedPreferences`:  o que precisamos que fique claro é o seguinte: você não precisa do `Context` para essas tarefas e não deve passá-lo para o Model.  Crie uma abstração para as preferences e passe a instancia dessa classe. De novo, você pode criar ela na Injection recuperando o `Context` da `Application`. Ou ainda criá-la no `Presenter`, passando o `Context` para a classe `Injection` não precisar buscar da `Application`.

Comment: @felipe.rce Sim. Se você não que seguir por esse caminho, passe o Context para o Presenter e do Presenter para a Injection. Desse modo você não precisa passá-lo para o Model e também não recuperou da Application.

Comment: você fala passar o context pela interface ou pelo constructor?

Comment: Deixe esse método apenas `Context getContext();` na sua View. Assim você pode chamá-lo do Presenter e criar a classe `Database`, por exemplo. Ou ainda você pode mandar a classe `Database` já criada pelo construtor do `Presenter` (criada na `View` utilizando a `Injection).

Comment: achei a ideia de mandar a classe Database mais interessante, pois assim não estarei enviando algo do Android pra o presenter

Comment: @felipe.rce Ok, é uma boa abordagem. Mas não instancie direto na View. Abstraia para uma classe `Injection` (ou algo do tipo) e você ficara com uma implementação melhor e mais desacoplada. ;)